# Recursive bits reverse program

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, bit

Recursive reverse bits program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void displayBits( unsigned value );
void reverseBits( unsigned value, unsigned c );

int main( void )
{
    unsigned value;
    unsigned c = 32;

    printf( "Enter a unsigned integer: " );
    scanf( "%u", &value );   

    displayBits( value );
    printf( "%10s", "Reversed:    " );
    reverseBits( value , c );

    getche();
    return 0;
}

void displayBits( unsigned value )
{
     unsigned c;
     unsigned mask = 1 << 31;

     printf( "%10u = ", value );

     for( c = 1; c <= 32; c++ ){
          putchar( value & mask ? '1' : '0' );
          value <<= 1;
          if( c % 8 == 0 )
              putchar( ' ' );

          }//end for    
     putchar( '\n' );

}

void reverseBits( unsigned value, unsigned c )
{
     unsigned mask = 1 << 31;

     if( c == 0 ){
         return;

         }//end if

     else{     
          value <<= 1;
          reverseBits( value , c - 1 );
          putchar( value & mask ? '1' : '0' );
          if( c % 8 == 0 ){
              putchar( ' ' );

              }//end if
          }//end else
}
```

When I input 15 it outputs

```
01111000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

instead of

```
11110000 00000000 00000000 000000000.
```

Comment: You are only out by 1 bit. So pretty close. What have you done to try and debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 else{     
      value <<= 1;//<-- Value has been changed before it can be used
      reverseBits( value , c - 1 );
      putchar( value & mask ? '1' : '0' );
      if( c % 8 == 0 ){
          putchar( ' ' );

          }//end if
      }//end else
```

replace with

```
else {
    reverseBits(value << 1, c - 1 );
    putchar( value & mask ? '1' : '0' );
    if( c % 8 == 0 ){
        putchar( ' ' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what does your code do? What is the purpose of `c`? Why you then divide `c` by 8 and take the mod?

Answer (score 0):

If you will try you current code for a number in which all bits are set, then you'll come to know about your mistake. In case of all bits are set, your program will return following o/p.

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
instead of
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

That is because you are shifting first bit of given number 32 times(positions), instead of 31. so you have to change your logic. You can do it as pointed out by @BLUEPIXY.